# How to use Spring @RequestMapping annotation programmatically (DispatcherServlet)

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, request-mapping

Let's say i want to create a controller class "MyController" and inside it I want to annotate the various method with the spring  @RequestMapping annotation:

```
-@RequestMapping("/employee-management/employees")
    public String getAllEmployees(Model model)
-@RequestMapping("/employee-management/employee/{someID}")
    public String getEmployee(@PathVariable(value="someID") String id)
```

I want to call this controller in a main java method like this:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
  HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
  when(httpServletRequest1.getRequestURI()).thenReturn("/employee-management/employee/122");
  DispatcherServlet MyDispatcherServlet= new DispatcherServlet();

//     [here i want to init MyDispatcherServlet with the httpServletRequest object] and i want it to call the appropriate method mapped within "MyController" class]
```

I want all this to run outside of a container (eg. tomcat).

Comment: Do you want to run the test ?

Comment: no, i want to use my controller with a HttpServletRequest object coming from elsewhere.

Comment: the test was written just to clarify on how i want to use my controller. I need to know how to instantiate the DispatcherServlet properly

Comment: The controllers are Servlets, so they run in a Servlet container. You can use SpringBoot, it generate a fat jar that include a container inside. You only need to execute the jar and that's all.

Comment: If you need to invoke a method of a controller, then you need to make a HTTP request. You can do this inside a main class, the call is a remote call, so you main class will run in a different jar.